# Get value for keys within a range in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table as below. How can I find value of i1 or i2 or i3 if user input in the range of X ? Thanks

```
--------------------------
|   X    | i1 | i2 | i3  |
|--------|---------------|
|  0-50  |  0 | -1 |  2  |
|------------------------|   
| 51-100 | -1 | -1 |  1  |
|------------------------|   
|101-150 | -2 |  1 |  2  |
|------------------------|   
|        ..........      |
|------------------------|   
|________________________|
```

Comment: How can I do it in javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill out this table with your data :

```
            var table = [["0-50",0,-1,2],["51-100",-1,-1,1],["101-150",-2,1,2]];
```

Then call this function : first parameter is the number to find and the second is the value you want (i1 :1, i2:2, i3:3)

```
            function FindNumber(val, index)
            {
                for(i=0;i<table.length;i++)
                {
                    var range = table[i][0].split("-");
                    if(val >= range[0] && val <= range[1])
                    {
                        return table[i][index];
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: you so smart, I can't think about it. Thanks for your help